# same SQL concatenation opeartor for mysql,mssql,oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, plsql

I am trying to use same sql statement for the above three DBMS .. but the problem is that it has string concatenation involved but there are different ways in each dbms for concatenation operation .. but i want the single operator .. Need someone's help

Comment: Not likely to happen, but an example of what you're trying/wanting would help

Comment: Denali has the `CONCAT` function but until then in TSQL you are stuck with `+`

Comment: Is it possible to define a concat function in sql server .. same as the CONCAT in mysql,oracle

Comment: @ahmedsaud - No. All user defined functions in SQL Server need to be prefixed with schema so you could define a `CONCAT` function but you would need to call it as `dbo.CONCAT`. Additionally UDFs can't take variable length parameter lists.

Comment: yeah i know it can't take variable length parameters

Comment: You are out of luck here. Although MySQL can be configured to follow the ANSI standard and use `||` as the concatenation operator (just like Oracle and nearly every other SQL database out there), there is no way to convince SQL Server to be standard's compliant

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - [There is a way of doing this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718276/same-sql-concatenation-opeartor-for-mysql-mssql-oracle/7778685#7778685)

Answer (score 3):

You can perhaps get around this in your application code by using a placeholder for concatenation in your sql statements, and then replacing it with the correct style for the rdbms you are using:

```
select {conpre} myfield1 {conmid} myfield2 {conmid} myfield3 {conend}
  from mytable
```

Then in pseudo-code:

```
if rdbms is sqlserver
    conpre = ""
    conmid = " + "
    conend = ""
else if rdbms is mysql
    conpre = "concat("
    conmid = ", "
    conend = ")"
else if rdbms is oracle
    conpre = ""
    conmid = " || "
    conend = ""
else if
    ' etc...
end if

stmt = replace(stmt, "{conpre}", conpre)
stmt = replace(stmt, "{conmid}", conmid)
stmt = replace(stmt, "{conend}", conend)
```

Comment: Sorry ... It is not the answer i expect as If this is .. then why not I handle this in programming..

Comment: The correct answer to your "question" is `no`.  Just thought I'd offer another suggestion to be more helpful.

Comment: It is possible I think. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid writing your own solution to the problem and use one of the muti-database tools already available. If you have come across this problem once you will come across it again soon.

I've no affiliation with the following but you could try [Datanamic Multirun](http://www.datanamic.com/multirun/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to the question seems to be no.

However...

What if you create the package dbo in Oracle?
Is it not also possible in mysql to create a function called concat in a separate database called dbo, so that a function is called using the syntax dbo.concat(a, b, c)?

Unfortunately, mysql doesn't support default parameters(unless recently changed) or function overloading, so you would have to create on function for each number of arguments:

concat2(s1, s2)

concat3(s1, s2, s3)

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way of doing this using ODBC escape sequences

```
SELECT {fn concat (col1, {fn concat (col2, col3)})}
FROM YourTable
```

From [my current understanding](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6855/will-fn-concat-work-without-issue-in-mysql-sql-server-and-oracle) this will work fine in SQL Server and MySQL but for Oracle is dependant upon connection method.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I don't know exactly. In SQL Server it seems connection agnostic. You can create a stored procedure with this in the definition and it caches a plan for it with `fn concat` in the text itself rather than it being rewritten by the driver before it gets to SQL Server. I'll probably post a question about it on dba.stackexchange.com later

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL:**

```
   SELECT CONCAT('New ', 'York ', 'City');
```

Output is : New York City

**Oracle:**

```
SELECT 'The city' || ' is ' || 'Paris' FROM dual;
```

Output is :  The city is Paris

**SQL Server:**

```
SELECT 'The city' + ' is ' + 'Paris';
```

Output is :  The city is Paris

```
 SELECT CONCAT('The city', ' is ', 'Paris');
```

Output is : The city is Paris